# Uniqueness of homomorphism from $S_A \rightarrow S_A$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

For any nonempty set $A$ the symmetric group $S_A$  acts on $A$ by $\rho a=\rho (a)$, for all $\rho \in S_A, a \in A$. The associated permutation representation (homomorphism from $S_A \rightarrow S_A$) is the identity map from $S_A$ to $S_A$.
Is this the only permutation representation? Why?

Comment: What context is in your mind?

Comment: There are plenty of other permutation representations on sets larger than $A$. There is the regular representation for example. For $A$ finite, up to equivalence, it is the only faithful permutation represenation on the set $A$, except in the case $|A|=6$, when there is a second such representation.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of nontrivial automorphisms of $S_A$.

Each automorphism of $S_A$ will give a nontrivial permutation representation of $S_A$.

Comment: And when $|A|=6$ there's even a non-trivial outer automorphism, and otherwise they're all inner (when $|A|>4$).